# Fetch data from Siebel CRM

Tags: ios, siebel

I'm planning to develop an adapter to access Siebel CRM data for my iOS app. I'm a new bee into this Siebel technology. I 've the Siebel CRM up an running in my workstation with sample db data. Could any one help me in getting this done? please excuse me if i've hosted this ques in a wrong stack.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be only 2 valid ways to do that:

- SOAP webservices
- REST api (but for this you need to have jboss or weblogic server: [Sebel Bookshelf](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/SAI_OFM/SAI_OFMTOC.html))

all other ways (Java Siebel Data Bean, COM interfaces, direct db access) got lots of issues: like issues with java on iOS ( I think it is not possible to run on iPhone), issues with legacy COM interfaces on iOS and numerous issues with direct db connection (complexity, stability, reusability...)

SOAP is out of the box on Siebel but requires more coding on iOS side, REST is easier on iOS or any webpage but requires some middlware:

- JBoss/WebLogic + and RESTfull Siebel client form Siebel (available somewhere on their page)
- java data bean app that produces REST
- soap client that produces REST

I have worked on 2 projects involving iOS and Siebel: first one using JBoss and second project that used SOAP client which translated requests to/from REST. SOAP client approach was more stable (in comparison to RESTfull client from vendor - as the RESTfull client connects to Siebel internally using Java Data Bean) on Siebel 7.8.

In both cases we picked REST to talk to iOS as it allows easier deveopment on iOS side and also possiblity to easly utilize it in projects creating webpages to simplify/tune siebel GUI for different purpose..

Answer (score 0):

If you're current system is sample db, then you have installed developer instance of Siebel. It uses a Sybase database. The server installation will use Oracle/MSSQL server. If you are ok with database connection, you can check that.

For Webservices, by default , Siebel does not support JSON/REST api. Only the older SOAP structure is supported. You will have to go through oracle bookshelves to setup an inbound webservice in Siebel.

But just to add, the latest version of Siebel's UI uses javascript/CSS, and runs on any browser, including IOs .